# How to prevent automatic preformatting when lines begin with a space

Tags: html, mediawiki

I am using a private Mediawiki and another software which automatically creates pages. I now have the problem that some of the created content has got monospaced font although normal font should be applied.

I found out that Mediawiki automatically adds a `<pre>` under certain circumstances:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
 automatic pre
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
normal text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The cell containing `automatic pre` will be displayed in monospaced font. If I removed the leading whitespace, the text would be rendered normally.

[image]

I am not able to alter the content created by the other application. I just wonder if it was possible to render the content of the first cell not monospaced?

Furthermore, I would be grateful if someone could tell me where I could find some documentation about this behaviour.

Comment: I think this actually has nothing to do with tables: MediaWiki syntax treats any line starting with at least one space that way, just as Markdown does if there are at least four leading spaces. I don't know if there's a way to prevent it, though.

Comment: See the row mentioning "Preformatted text": https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting

Comment: Might be simpler to trim whitespace from the output of your other program, or to override styling for `pre` elements with CSS.

Comment: Thank you all - I will take another look at the other application or add styling for `pre` elements.